# Are there first and rest functions in iracket?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, racket

I just set up iracket. But some functions seems doesn't work.

```
(define (f z) (first (rest z)))
(f '(1 2 3))
first: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition
  in module: top-level
  internal name: first
  context...:
```

I'm wondering are there first and rest functions in iracket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IRacket starts with the bindings of the `racket/base` module, which doesn't include `first` and `rest`. Run `(require racket/list)` or `(require racket)` before your function definition.